# show that 4 colors is sufficient to color any penny graph whithout using the Four Color Theorem.

Tags: graph-theory

(A *penny graph* is a graph formed by arranging pennies in a non-overlapping way on a flat surface, making a vertex for each penny, and making an edge for each two pennies that touch.)

I am asked to use proof by contradiction; consider the 2 pennies with the largest geometric distance and use the idea of critical graph.

I don't understand how the 2 pennies with the largest geometric distance can work with the idea of critical graph. Am I going to consider the subgraph without these 2 pennies?

Can someone give some hints? Thank you!

Comment: See https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/674691/finding-a-vertex-of-degree-3-in-a-penny-graph-to-prove-that-it-can-be-4-colored

Answer (score 2):

I’ll phrase it as a direct proof, but the can be easily modified to give a proof by contradiction in the way that the Wharton asks.

Consider the furthest distance circles. They both have degree at most 3. You can use them to prove that the penny graph has [degeneracy](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degeneracy_(graph_theory)) at most three. It will then follow that the coloring number is at most $4$. If this last step is unclear, try to color the image at the top of the linked page from left to right.

Answer (score 2):

Suppose the theorem is false. Then there's a penny graph which can only be colored with five colors. Now if there's a vertex in this graph which we can remove without changing the 5-color property, let's remove it—and repeat this procedure, until we're left with a graph which we'll call $G$. $G$ has the following properties:

1. $G$ is a penny graph.
2. $G$ can only be colored with five colors.
3. If you delete any vertex from $G$, it no longer has the previous property.

Because of property (3), $G$ is a critical graph—deleting any vertex lowers the chromatic number of $G$.

---

Using the relationship between critical graphs and degrees, you can argue that every vertex in $G$ has at least four (= 5-1) neighbors. (Can you prove this?)

But using the properties of penny graphs, you can argue that the vertices of $G$ which are furthest apart each have at most 3 neighbors. (Can you prove this?)

These two results contradict each other. Therefore no such 5-color penny graph can exist.